# Facebook C# SDK Send Gift

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to send gift request to User rather than to post on wall is it possible?
I have access token of that User and i can send him post to wall but not know how i can send request or notification?

```
 var app = new Facebook.FacebookClient(oAuthAccessToken);


        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "test";
        parameters.category = "Application";
        //category

        dynamic id = app.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

thanks